# The copy/move window in Krusader in Ubuntu 17.04?

Tags: 17.04, krusader

In previous versions of Ubuntu and the versions of the Krusader file manager corresponding to them I used to have the copy/move window, which was showing the operation progress as a file was copied or moved.

I cannot remember what the versions of Krusader were exactly, but now, in Ubuntu 17.04 it is Version 2.5.0 "Clear Skies" and when a file is being copied or moved there is no information of the operation progress.

I tried to restore the default settings, searched for any information about this issue and the only thing I found was [a blog post](https://rohlix.wordpress.com/2016/08/19/krusader-copymove-dialog-not-visible/), which though did not help me, but at least stated that this is a common and repeating problem with Krusader.

Could anyone help with this, or at least say whether they are having the same issue since their update to 17.04?